# Solve $2n^3 + 3n^2 + n = d$

Tags: diophantine-equations, cubics

how to solve the following Diophantine equation?
$$
2n^3+3n^2+n=d
$$
Here, $n$ and $d$ are non-negative integers.
It would also be great if it were possible to formulate an algorithm for
$$
an^3 +bn^2 +n c= d
$$
for arbitrary coprime integers $a$, $b$, $c$.

Comment: Note that the equation implies $n\mid d$.

Comment: As Hagen von Eitzen implicitly points out, solving your equation is equivalent to solving $2n^2 + 3n + 1 = d$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be written as $n(n+1)(2n+1)=d$. The left-hand side satisfies

$$2n^3 < n(n+1)(2n+1) < 2(n+1)^3$$

So $n^3 < d/2 < (n+1)^3$, which means that the only possible integer solution is

$$n=\left\lfloor \sqrt[3] {d/2}\right\rfloor$$

and you just have to check whether this satisfies the equation.

Comment: I think you should drop the $+1$ term, e.g. try with $d = 6$ or $d = 30$.

Comment: @A.P.: Thank you! I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$ 2n^3 + 3n^2 + n = d \Longleftrightarrow $$
$$ -d + 2n^3 + 3n^2 + n= 0 \Longleftrightarrow $$

---

Eliminate the quadratic term bij substituting $x=n+\frac{1}{2}$:

---

$$-\frac{1}{2}-d+3\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+2\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^3+x=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-d-\frac{x}{2}+2x^3=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-\frac{d}{2}-\frac{x}{4}+x^3=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

If $x=y+\frac{\lambda}{y}$ then $y=\frac{1}{2}\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-4\lambda}\right)$ which will be used during back substitution:

---

$$-\frac{d}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\left(-y-\frac{\lambda}{y}\right)+\left(y+\frac{\lambda}{y}\right)^3=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-\frac{dy^3}{2}+y^6+\lambda^3+y^4\left(3\lambda-\frac{1}{4}\right)+y^2\left(3\lambda^2-\frac{\lambda}{4}\right)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Substitute $\lambda=\frac{1}{12}$ and the $z=y^3$, yielding a quadratic equation in the variable $z$:

---

$$\frac{1}{1728}-\frac{dz}{2}+z^2=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\frac{1}{72}\left(18d+\sqrt{3}\sqrt{108d^2-1}\right)$$

From now on you've to substitute everything back and solve $n$.

Comment: 1. The hint uses the wrong equation: it is $2n^3 + 3n^2 + \mathbf{n} = d$, not $2n^3 + 3n^2 + c = d$. 2. The OP is asking about a *Diophantine* equation, i.e. for *integer* solutions to the given equation. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it doesn't look like in your answer you are addressing the issue as to weather $n$ and $d$ are integers or not.

Comment: Ive edited my answer, now it is true!

Comment: You addressed the first part of my comment, but not the second one: the OP is asking about the *integer* solutions to the equation $2n^3 + 3n^2 + n = d$. You proved that this equation admits exactly one positive real solution when $d \geq 1$, but you didn't address the problem of determining when this solution is integer. For example for $d = 1$ the solution isn't integer, but for $d = 6$ it is.

Comment: I know and understand the question, but I gave a hint on looking for integer solutions

Comment: Could you please make your hint more clear, then? Right now it looks like you are only talking about solving for $n$ real.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $n = 0$ or $d = 0$ the only solution is $(0,0)$, so it is enough to consider $n,d$ positive. Then the equation
$$
2n^3 + 3n^2 + n = d \tag{1}
$$
is equivalent to the equation
$$
2n^2 + 3n + 1 = d' \tag{2} \label{eq:reduced}
$$
which has the only positive solution
$$
n = \frac{-3 + \sqrt{9 + 8(d'-1)}}{4}.
$$
All that's left is figure out when this number is an integer... and currently I don't know how to do that.

---

On the other hand, a quick numerical analysis suggests that the values of $d'$ for which \eqref{eq:reduced} has integer solutions are precisely those of the form
$$
d' = 2k^2 + 7k + 6 \quad \text{for } k \in \Bbb{Z}_{\geq 0} \tag{3} \label{eq:fit}
$$
(I checked this equation for $d' < 10^8$).

A (somewhat messy, but exact) way to compute those values of $d'$ less than $10000$ in Sage is

```
map(lambda x: x+1, filter(lambda k: is_square(9+8*k) and (-3 + sqrt(9+8*k) % 4) == 0, range(2,10000)))
```

Plotting each of these numbers against its index suggests a quadratic relationship

[image: Plot of the values of d' less than 10000 for which n is integer]

and a quick fitting gives the coefficients in \eqref{eq:fit}.

Comment: Err...the values of $d'$ for which (2) has integer solutions are precisely those of the form $2n^2+3n+1$, obviously. Put $k=n-1$ and this becomes $2(k+1)^2+3(k+1)+1 = 2k^2+7k+6$.

Comment: @TonyK :facepalm: Of course!